# How to include the last object in a queueing simulation? Simpy-Python

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am reffering to this example : https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/carwash.html

If you see the output of this algorithm, the last car/object that arrived did not depart because the simulation has been completed. I would like to modify the algorithm such as the server completes servicing all those cars that are already in the system in simulation time. I have tried a lot, but I did not succeed.

```
"""
Carwash example.

Covers:

- Waiting for other processes
- Resources: Resource

Scenario:
  A carwash has a limited number of washing machines and defines
  a washing processes that takes some (random) time.

  Car processes arrive at the carwash at a random time. If one washing
  machine is available, they start the washing process and wait for it
  to finish. If not, they wait until they an use one.

"""
import random

import simpy


RANDOM_SEED = 42
NUM_MACHINES = 2  # Number of machines in the carwash
WASHTIME = 5      # Minutes it takes to clean a car
T_INTER = 7       # Create a car every ~7 minutes
SIM_TIME = 20     # Simulation time in minutes


class Carwash(object):
    """A carwash has a limited number of machines (``NUM_MACHINES``) to
    clean cars in parallel.

    Cars have to request one of the machines. When they got one, they
    can start the washing processes and wait for it to finish (which
    takes ``washtime`` minutes).

    """
    def __init__(self, env, num_machines, washtime):
        self.env = env
        self.machine = simpy.Resource(env, num_machines)
        self.washtime = washtime

    def wash(self, car):
        """The washing processes. It takes a ``car`` processes and tries
        to clean it."""
        yield self.env.timeout(WASHTIME)
        print("Carwash removed %d%% of %s's dirt." %
              (random.randint(50, 99), car))


def car(env, name, cw):
    """The car process (each car has a ``name``) arrives at the carwash
    (``cw``) and requests a cleaning machine.

    It then starts the washing process, waits for it to finish and
    leaves to never come back ...

    """
    print('%s arrives at the carwash at %.2f.' % (name, env.now))
    with cw.machine.request() as request:
        yield request

        print('%s enters the carwash at %.2f.' % (name, env.now))
        yield env.process(cw.wash(name))

        print('%s leaves the carwash at %.2f.' % (name, env.now))


def setup(env, num_machines, washtime, t_inter):
    """Create a carwash, a number of initial cars and keep creating cars
    approx. every ``t_inter`` minutes."""
    # Create the carwash
    carwash = Carwash(env, num_machines, washtime)

    # Create 4 initial cars
    for i in range(4):
        env.process(car(env, 'Car %d' % i, carwash))

    # Create more cars while the simulation is running
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(t_inter - 2, t_inter + 2))
        i += 1
        env.process(car(env, 'Car %d' % i, carwash))


# Setup and start the simulation
print('Carwash')

random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)  # This helps reproducing the results

# Create an environment and start the setup process
env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(setup(env, NUM_MACHINES, WASHTIME, T_INTER))

# Execute!
env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

Comment: I modified the " while True " that is in the setup function such that: while True and env.now>T. But it does not work.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I did it ......

Comment: What you should have done in your question is to tell us what "you tried" and what changed in your output, so we can know what you have applied and where to look with you, instead of putting the whole code again.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this matter, you need to check the Car processes count. As long as it is positive, don't stop simulation.

```
while True:
    yield env.timeout(random.randint(t_inter - 2, t_inter + 2))
    i += 1
    env.process(car(env, 'Car %d' % i, carwash))
```

Try to tweak the while function to be your last arriving car. Your simulation time is when your world ceases to exist, not when your car generation stops.
For example, you can create a setter for the SIM_TIME so that for every car in your system, you give it the time it needs. Instead of using `until=SIM_TIME` you can use `env.exit()`

[env.exit() reference](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.core.html#simpy.core.Environment.exit)

[env.run(until) reference](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.core.html#simpy.core.Environment.run)